# How can I enable Intel's P-State driver?

Tags: linux-kernel, cpu-frequency

I am trying to use Intel's P-State driver for my custom-built kernel (based on Linux 4.4.55). I have enabled the driver in the kernel configuration (by setting the `X86_INTEL_PSTATE` flag to "`*`"), but my kernel somehow still uses the old `ACPI_CPUFREQ` driver. I have verified that `intel_pstate.c` is compiled to `intel_pstate.o` in the kernel sources (in `/drivers/cpufreq`).

I think the `intel_pstate` driver is enabled by default, but just in case I still tried adding `intel_pstate=enable` to the `GRUB_CMD_LINE_DEFAULT` variable in `/etc/default/grub.cfg`. Nothing changed, however.

What should I do to enable the Intel P-State driver in my kernel? Why is this driver somehow not built-in?

Comment: Compiled in or as a module? Is the module installed?

Comment: @ajeh Compiled in. Only acpi-cpufreq module installed according to lsmod.

Comment: Try blacklisting the other module and see what happens. Failing that, perhaps you can contact the developer hoping they can provide instructions. I assume you made sure that your CPU is compatible with the P-state driver.

Comment: @ajeh I have tried blacklisting acpi-freq module, which result in "no or unknown cpufreq driver" according to cpufreq-info. I also tested another server with same hardware configuration running regular 4.4.0 kernel and P-State driver is working fine.

Comment: Most likely, either your particular CPU is blacklisted by the driver, or the firmware isn't providing the information needed for the `intel-pstate` driver.

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn I don't think my CPU is blacklisted by the driver. Both servers are running the exact cpu (xeon 5118) and all other hardware aspect. Right now I am just going through the default config file for 4.4.55 and see if any changes in the custom kernel is causing the intel-pstate driver not to install.

Comment: What is your distro and where did you obtain the kernel source? `uname -a`

Comment: @ajeh Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS with kernel  version 4.4.55

Comment: I know that on Fedora the kernel is thoroughly patched and the stock kernels do not tend to work. So if you are trying kernel.org kernel, it may be playing tricks with you. My knowledge ends here.

Answer (score 1):

Linux didn't fix this bug until 4.4.0-75.96 I patched a 4.4.137 intel-pstate driver file to 4.4.55 and it works again. The original bug report is at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1674390

Comment: You originally wrote yours was 4.4.55, something does not add up.

Comment: @ajeh I am still using 4.4.55, but I found the fix didn't happen until 4.4.0-75.96, so I backported the change to my 4.4.55 version. 4.4.0.75-96 and 4.4.137 has no change in intel_pstate that I am aware of.

Comment: 4.4.0 is lower than 4.4.55, so something still does not add up. 4.4.55 should have everything that appeared in 4.4.0. What am I missing?

Comment: @ajeh My guess is that ubuntu just number kernel version differently.

Comment: @ajeh 4.4.0.75-95 actually correspond to 4.4.59 which is higher than 4.4.55 check this link https://people.canonical.com/~kernel/info/kernel-version-map.html